# Possible values of current_session_context_class property in hibernate and uses

Tags: hibernate, session

I  wanted to know all possible values that can be used with `current_session_context_class` property in cfg.xml file? I have an idea of thread value that makes the session context to relate per thread, like `propertyname="current_session_context_class"` thread.

Answer (score 13):

For Hibernate 4 valid values include:

1. *jta*, *thread*, and *managed* (which are aliases for implementations delivered with Hibernate).
2. full class name with package to any other custom class that
   implements `org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentSessionContext`

This is told in [Hibernate manual - 2.3. Contextual sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-current-session)

Comment: does current_session_context_class property have any default value or we have to explicitly defined it in cfg.xml file . I mean we need to explixitly tell the session context in cfg,xml or session context have some defalut implementation among jta, thread,manage

Comment: If not defined JTA will be used.

Comment: [@JavaCreature](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2714179/javacreature): based on my recent efforts to implement and test such code, the [relevant Hibernate documentation section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch02.html#architecture-current-session) and the [Javadocs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/context/spi/CurrentSessionContext.html), I do not believe that `current_session_context_class` has a default value.

Comment: Which one is the default value?