# Spring ampq consumer - "No Session found for current thread" error in first attempt

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-transactions, spring-amqp

I have a Spring MVC application. I want to use spring ampq to execute my asynchronous tasks. 
My REST backend uses @Transactional annotation to manage the transactions. After doing its work it pushes a task to the exhange and then returns. Then the task is received by a consumer, which in its first attempt receives a "org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread" error. Then spring-ampq retries to send the task to the consumer and this time it works, without any session error.

How can I make this scenario work in the first attempt?

My spring ampq configuration is similar to this (http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/):

```
<rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    exchange="myExchange" routing-key="foo.bar"/>

<rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

<rabbit:queue name="myQueue" />

<rabbit:topic-exchange name="myExchange">
    <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="myQueue" pattern="foo.*" />
    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>


<rabbit:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory"  advice-chain="retryInterceptor">
    <rabbit:listener ref="foo" method="listen" queue-names="myQueue" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="foo" class="foo.Foo" />

<bean id="retryInterceptor" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageRecoverer" ref="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"/>
    <property name="retryOperations" ref="retryTemplate"/>
    <property name="messageKeyGeneretor" ref="bodyBasedKeyGenerator"/>
</bean>
<bean id="bodyBasedKeyGenerator" class="com.mydomain.util.BodyBasedKeyGenerator"/>
<bean id="rejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.retry.RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer"/>

<bean id="retryTemplate" class="org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate">
    <property name="backOffPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy">
            <property name="initialInterval" value="5000"/>
            <property name="maxInterval" value="120000"/>
            <property name="multiplier" value="2"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="retryPolicy">
        <bean class="org.springframework.retry.policy.SimpleRetryPolicy">
            <property name="maxAttempts" value="1"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note: foo.Foo listen() method is also annotated with @Transactional.

My transaction manager is configured as follows:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.mydomain.bean"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

Note: The session factory is initiazed deep in the dao factory. I am using the same dao factory both in the REST service and rabbit consumer.

My error log is as follows:

```
06:48:16,141 DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer] - Storing delivery for Consumer: tag=[amq.ctag-K3ZRHRBVttW20ROENd9l4g], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@192.168.1.21:5672/,3), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
06:48:16,142 DEBUG [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer] - Received message: (Body:'73'; ID:null; Content:application/x-java-serialized-object; Headers:{}; Exchange:exchange; RoutingKey:foo.dummy.dummy2; Reply:null; DeliveryMode:PERSISTENT; DeliveryTag:1)
06:48:16,143 DEBUG [org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor] - Executing proxied method in stateful retry: public abstract void org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$ContainerDelegate.invokeListener(com.rabbitmq.client.Channel,org.springframework.amqp.core.Message) throws java.lang.Exception(2fe83585)
06:48:16,146 TRACE [org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate] - RetryContext retrieved: [RetryContext: count=0, lastException=null, exhausted=false]
06:48:16,146 DEBUG [org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate] - Retry: count=0
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Creating new transaction with name [foo.Foo.listen]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
06:48:16,147 TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] - Opened session at timestamp: 13881430961
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl] - begin
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Obtaining JDBC connection
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Obtained JDBC connection
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction] - initial autocommit status: true
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction] - disabling autocommit
06:48:16,147 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler@60c58418[valid=true]]
06:48:16,147 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@52a971e3] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@3c250cce] to thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]
06:48:16,147 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder@7274187a] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@68e26d2e] to thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]
06:48:16,147 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Initializing transaction synchronization
06:48:16,147 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] - Getting transaction for [foo.Foo.listen]
06:48:16,153 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor#0'
06:48:16,153 TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] - Opened session at timestamp: 13881430961
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] - Completing transaction for [foo.Foo.listen] after exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - Winning rollback rule is: null
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute] - No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Initiating transaction rollback
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl] - rolling back
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction] - rolled JDBC Connection
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction] - re-enabling autocommit
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl] - after transaction completion
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] - after transaction completion
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Clearing transaction synchronization
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionHolder@7274187a] for key [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl@68e26d2e] from thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager] - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@52a971e3] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@3c250cce] from thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler] - Handling invocation of connection method [isReadOnly]
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager] - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl] - Closing session
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Closing logical connection
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl] - Closing JDBC container [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceRegistryImpl@5ef23a26]
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Releasing JDBC connection
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Released JDBC connection
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler] - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler] - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
06:48:16,154 DEBUG [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.ConnectionProxyHandler] - HHH000163: Logical connection releasing its physical connection
06:48:16,154 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl] - Logical connection closed
06:48:16,155 DEBUG [org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate] - Checking for rethrow: count=1
06:48:16,155 DEBUG [org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate] - Rethrow in retry for policy: count=1
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'listen' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:457)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:358)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:546)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:472)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor$MethodInvocationRetryCallback.doWithRetry(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:255)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:188)
    at org.springframework.retry.interceptor.StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.invoke(StatefulRetryOperationsInterceptor.java:145)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy51.invokeListener(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:611)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:454)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:474)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:458)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:551)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:978)
    at com.mydomain.dao.ListingDaoImpl.getListing(ListingDaoImpl.java:38)
    at com.mydomain.dataaccess.DataProvider.getListing(DataProvider.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at $Proxy29.getListing(Unknown Source)
    at foo.Foo.listen(Foo.java:32)
    at foo.Foo$$FastClassByCGLIB$$1e4b772c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at foo.Foo$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$714aa208.listen(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:451)
    ... 26 more
```

The listener code is as follows:

```
package foo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private IDataProvider dataProvider;

    @Transactional
    public void listen(Long listingId) throws Exception {

        dataProvider.getListing(listingId);
    }
}
```

The code for the REST backend is similar to this:

```
@Controller
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@RequestMapping(value = { "/myController" })
public class MyController extends BaseController {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate exchangeTemplate;

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody MyClass update(@RequestBody MyClass myclass, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        getAuthorizationManager().authorizeUserFromRequest(request);
        List<MyClass> result = getDataProvider().update(myclass);
        exchangeTemplate.convertAndSend("foo.Foo.update", myclass.getId())
        return result;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't shown an Exception StackTrace. And add, please, the code of your listener. Maybe there is no reason to add `@Transactional`...

Comment: @artem I have updated the question with the error stacktrace and the code for the listener. Without `@Transactional` all the attempts fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be in the initialization of sessionfactory. I had a static getDao function and the SessionFactory instance was also static:

```
@Repository
public class DaoFactory {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        DaoFactory.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public static HibernateDaoBase getDao(Class<?> className) {
     .
     .
```

I got it working by making the getDao function non-static and autowiring the DaoFactory class into the DataProvider class:

```
@Repository
public class DaoFactory {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public HibernateDaoBase getDao(Class<?> className) {
     .
     .
```

and

```
@Repository
@EnableCaching
public class DataProvider implements IDataProvider {

    @Autowired
    private DaoFactory daoFactory;
```

Answer (score 4):

OK. Now I see where is an issue.
You are using `LocalSessionFactoryBean`, who is based on `SpringSessionContext`, who, in turn, wants to have a `SessionHolder` in the transactional resources within `ThreadLocal`. But as far as AMQP Listener works within his own Thread, there is no any hook which register `sessionFactory` in the transactional resources. Something like `OpenSessionInViewFilter` for Spring MVC.

Try to use

```
hibernate.current_session_context_class = local
```

as `hibernateProperties` for `LocalSessionFactoryBean`.
I have never used `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. The JTA `SessionFactory` from EE container JNDI always works perfectly for all cases.

UPDATE:

Well, as far as you may use the same `IDataProvider` from MVC and from AMQP Listener, and the issue is around the `CurrentSessionContext`, where there is no `currentSession` within AMQP Thread, you have to do `sessionFactory.openSession()` manually from code of your `IDataProvider` implementation and only in case, if there is no `currentSession` within `currentSessionContext`. Something like this:

```
Session hibernateSession = null;
try {
   hibernateSession = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}
catch(HibernateException he) {
    hibernateSession = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
}
```

Of course, you can write your onw `SpringSessionContext` variant and move that code to the `currentSession()`

I don't understand why it works the second attempt from Retry for you. In my test-case it fails anyway.

Suppose there is something in your configuration, which takes care about `currentSession`, but you don't mention it.

HTH

Comment: I have looked into "hibernate.current_session_context_class" property but it seems 'local' is not a valid value for it: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422044/possible-values-of-current-session-context-class-propety-in-hibernate-and-uses]. Yet I understand the point you are trying to make. One problem for me is that I use Tomcat as the server and did not setup a transaction manager within it until now. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552612/how-to-use-jta-support-in-tomcat-6-for-hibernate]

Comment: Still, I dont see the reason why the session gets bounded in the second trial. Then would not that fail too?

Comment: This thread suggests not to use current_session_context_class unless you use JTA which unfortunetely I am not. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832889/spring-transactions-and-hibernate-current-session-context-class]

Comment: Right, I understand the issue. I see only one way to fix it: implement your own interceptor, something similar to `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` and use it together with `@Transactional`

Comment: I am not sure I can manage that. From what I understand, the interceptor needs to "register `sessionFactory` in the transactional resources". I still cant understand why it is registered in the second attempt but not in the first one. Also, since OpenSessionInViewInterceptor is a web request interceptor, but this new interceptor will not be, do I need to be familiar with AOP framework which again unfortunately I am not.

Comment: Yes, there is need to know AOP. Suppose you can understand why it works for the second time, when you go via debug through `HibernateTransactionManager`. I'll try later to reproduce it and understand. Sorry, it's something new for me too. Hope someone can help, though.

Comment: Your efforts until now are very much welcome, i should be sorry that i havent given enough appreciation until now.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more info. Happy New Year!

Comment: I have tried your update, there is no error but the transaction is not committed. Also after a few attempts to call the same service the server becomes unresponsive after the line "Obtaining JDBC connection" in the logs. Happy New Year to you too ;)

Comment: I have edited the question to show my REST backend and retryInterceptor advice-chain(in case it has something to do with the problem.)Also when I try your updated solution, when I call the REST service consecutively, in the first run there is no error but rabbit consumer transaction is not commited, in the second run current session is not null so works perfectly well and changes are commited, in the third run execution stalls with logs saying "Obtaining JDBC connection".I had also tried this approach: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/20549785/572380].Same result except for the deadlock.

Comment: "I have tried your update, there is no error but the transaction is   not committed. Also after a few attempts to call the same service the server becomes unresponsive after the line "Obtaining JDBC connection" in the logs."  <=== This means you are probably leaking connections someplace and not returning them to your connection pool.  This could possibly be related to your issue.