# Execute query with native query (update query) in Hibernate 5.x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am currently upgrading our application and we are migrating from **Hibernate 3.x** and **Spring/Spring Security 3.x** to **Hibernate 5.x** and **Spring/Spring Security 5.x** respectively. We had some methods that executed native sql update queries (example 1), but after upgrading to **5.x** the methods started throwing **TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query** exceptions. Well I tried adding the **@Transactional** annotation on the methods but it doesn't seem to help. I will share the old method and the upgraded method (example 2).

I don't understand how it is not working on the new version, did Hibernate change the way they treat native sql queries? Thanks for the responses.

**Example 1**

```
public void myTestMethod() {
    String sql = "Update myTable set State = 1";
    Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
    query.executeUpdate();
    session.close();
}
```

**Example 2**

```
public void myTestMethod() {
    String sql = "Update myTable set State = 1";
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.executeUpdate();
    session.close();
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I execute this update without changing much in the methods (we have thousands of methods implemented). The `sessionFactory` in the example 2 is injected with **@Inject** annotation.

Comment: do you have all database related beans created properly?

Comment: @kakabali `javax.persistence.transactionrequiredexception: executing an update/delete query`

Comment: try using the annotation `javax.transaction.Transactional` not the `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` or may be vice versa, it works for some people

Comment: are you using sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()?

Comment: @kakabali Please look at the examples that I shared!

Comment: oh sorry, try using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`

Comment: any good for you?

Comment: @kakabali replaced the openSession with getCurrentSession() and I got this exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@d68023 is closed`

Comment: you have transaction management in place? and if you are using the @Transactional on your methods? and try removing the line `session.close();`

Comment: in a @Transactional block, you don't need to manually manage the Hibernate Session

Comment: @kakabali what if I don't want to use the `@Transactional` annotation on my methods, I want to obtain the session by calling the openSession method and after I execute the query I close it. Is it somehow possible?

Comment: did it work for you? and the purpose of recent spring is not solved for transaction management, as per their guide

Comment: @kakabali after I removed the `session.close()` and using the `getCurrentSession` instead of `openSession` and the `@Transactional` annotation, it worked! But my question is how can I do it without the transactional annotation, I want to manage the session manually by opening and closing.

Comment: The alternate for it we will have to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `@Transactional` over your methods and use `getCurrentSession()` instead of the `openSession()`

And your code has `session.close()` statement which doesn't make sense any more, since the connection was already closed and managed by the spring. Try removing the `session.close()` statement and try again

Comment: Thanks, another question, what if I don't want to use the `@Transactional` annotation and I want to manage the session manually, what should I do?

Comment: very good question shahe, read something on `current_session_context_class` property for hibernate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422044/possible-values-of-current-session-context-class-property-in-hibernate-and-uses

Comment: http://rbyjava.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/what-is-currentsessioncontextclass-in.html

Comment: @kakabali I am getting **Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread** for `getCurrentSession()`

Comment: @Anothercoder spring boot or?? wats ur structure for ur setup?

Comment: SpringMVC after migrate, Spring 5.0.0.RELEASE to 3.2.2.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.2.0.Final to 5.2.11.Final